# textbox change event doesn't fire using append text using another method

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, onchange

I need to fire an event when change the valueof a textbox using change event.

**html**

```
'<select onchange="ChooseContact(this)">
 <option value='1'>1</option>
 <option value='2'>2</option></select>
 <input id="friendName">'
```

**JS**

```
function ChooseContact(data) {

document.getElementById ("friendName").value = data.value;

}

 $("#friendName").change(function(){
   alert("The text has been.");
  });

$('#friendName').bind('input propertychange', function() {
       alert("The text has been changed.");
});
```

here i tried to change select option value append to text. it will works fine.

textbox change event doesn't trigger also tried with `input propertychange`

if anybody know the reason please share here.

[I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/prasanthar/db2og88b/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are changing the value programatically, the change event will not get triggered automatically, instead you can trigger it manually

```js
function ChooseContact(data) {
  $('#friendName').val(data.value).change()
}

$("#friendName").change(function() {
  alert("The text has been.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="ChooseContact(this)">
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
<input id="friendName">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the event manually using:

```
 $("#friendName").change(function(){
       alert("The text has been.");
       $('#friendName').trigger('propertychange');
  });
```